# What does [...] mean used after .next function?

Tags: python, neural-network, iterator, slice

I'm reading a code on Neural Networks, i have this code:

```
test_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'test')
test=os.path.join(test_dir,'images/img')
image_filenames=next(os.walk(test))[2]
```

which is a simple access to a directory that contains my testing data.
The question is: what does the `[2]` mean used after the `next` function?

I've been searching on google, but i didn't find anything about it.

Comment: It means that the preceding expression evaluates to some kind of sequence, and you are taking the third element of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) yields a 3-tuple, consisting of `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`. The `[2]` just grabs the 3rd element of that tuple, as tuples are 0-indexed in python. So the returned value is `filenames`.